# Capturar valores através de um botão

Tags: java, android

Boa noite !
Estou desenvolvendo um app para realizar calculo do valor a faturar de mão de obra para clientes de acordo com o tipo de serviço. No entanto estou tendo dificuldade na ultima tela aonde vai gerar um relatorio de faturamento, queria ver como pegava esses valores das outras telas, lembrando que o valor de hora vai mudar de acordo com o tipo de serviço, mas o valores ja vou deixar definido no app. O usuario vai informar somente a quantidade de horas que ele realizou o serviço e o aplicativo retornara com o valor a ser cobrado. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você fala outras telas significa outras activities?

Se sim, você pode passar valores entre activities usando Bundle que você envia junto com o intent. [Aqui tem um bom exemplo sobre como usar o Bundle + Intent.](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/android-bundle-example/)

Ou ainda você pode utilizar variáveis estáticas para isso, apesar de não ser uma boa prática.

Sobre o botão, você pode adicionar um listener para pegar a ação ao clicar nele.

```
    botaoNovoCalculo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // seu código.
        }
    });
```

Comment: Isso mesmo ! vai ter outros activities aonde o usuário vai clicar e passar para a próxima tela adicionei nos botões o metodo trocatela.Dai ao clicar no botão ex.: botão Garantia( Que é um tipo de serviço) ele ja vai ir definido com o valor da hora a 100,00 Reais para a próxima tela que seria informar a quantidade de horas sendo que esses valores seriam multiplicados e exibidos na ultima tela do app que foi a que eu coloquei na pergunta. Dai queria ver como que fazia para atribuir esses valores fazer a multiplicação e exibir na ultima tela.

Comment: @EduardoRodrigues Dá uma olhada no link que postei. Ele é a sua solução.